# How to convert string to double without loosing any value

Tags: android, double

How to convert string to double without losing any value when I'm trying to convert double to string.

```
String num=5000.50;
String num1=5000.55;
System.out.prinltn("string to double parse value"+Double.valueOf(num))
System.out.prinltn("string to double parse       value"+Double.valueOf(num1))
output of num:5000.5
output of num1:5000.55(this is ok)
```

why it's losing last zero I'm confused why its happen?

Comment: double d= Double.parseDouble(yourString); try this.

Comment: this is not working

Comment: I'm stuck to this issue please help me to out this issue.